# How to store SSN as an integer using the format YYMMDD?

Tags: java, date, netbeans, int, date-format

I have to write a program that stores a SSN as an integer using the format YYMMDD. Also I need to figure out a way to print only the DD.

Example, if we store the SSN 800507 in an integer variable, the program should print 07 to the screen.
Now I have tried the following way, I am not sure if I am correctly dealing my first problem and I don't know how to solve my second issue( printing only the DD).

[Ops: I stored SSN in long variable because int doesn't work with too large numbers, since a SSN is a large int value, and I know that using long type doesn't match my requirement issue. That's why I need help how to solve it.]

```
    package ex1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //SSN in date formate starts
        Scanner iScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        long ssn;
        System.out.println("Enter your SSN in the formate YYDDMM:\n");
        ssn=iScanner.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Your SSN is:\n"+ssn);

         //SSN in date formate ends
```

Comment: A SSN contains 9 number Strings -- how can that be displayed as a String with 6 chars? I'm not sure that I understand what exactly it is you're trying to do. Also, a SSN should never be entered or treated as a number since it really isn't a number at all. You never do numeric operations on it for example. It's a String and should be treated as such.

Comment: Are you talking about US SSN?  Also, YYMMDD sounds like a date format.  Confused.

Comment: its basiacally european standard (Sweden in more specific). It works like this: YYMMDD:951230. So from there I need to print only the last two digits, the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow how your format is a SSN, but you could read it as a `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner iScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your SSN in the formate YYDDMM:\n");
    String ssn = iScanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(ssn.substring(ssn.length() - 2));
}
```

The issue with trying to use it numerically is leading zeros (remember that 01 is a valid output). You could use `String.format("%02d", 1)` but I'll leave that implementation to you.